# How to package a Java file

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to know the steps of packaging a java file in Eclipse to creating a .app or a .exe application.

Comment: Java is not meant to create an exe. You should create a JAR file. Do you know the difference between an exe and a JAR? If not, I strongly recommend to Google it.

Comment: you usually make an executable `jar` not an `exe`. Try doing an `Export Jar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export an [executable Jar](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse.html) file with eclipse and then use the [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to make a .exe to your application.

Answer (score 3):

You need to first create a jar, then use a program to pack that inside a executable.
Google "jar to exe"
Here's one.
http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/

Comment: You answered the question so far (+1), but one suggestion: tools like this don't really make an exe out of your application (like a C++ compiler would do for C++ code). The program just wraps the start-up of the JVM and your application into an exe. That could be misunderstood. There will always be a JVM.

Answer (score 0):

If this app. has a GUI, build Jars and provide the app. from a link ever the internet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS can deploy Java rich client desktop apps. to Windows, OS X & *nix, provides desktop integration, automatic updates and many other great features.